# How do I correctly set the HTTP Content-Disposition for large file names in Java?

Tags: java, http, content-disposition

I'm working on some requirements that will lead to arbitrary PDF files being downloaded from a J2EE web server. The names may look like this:

> Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - Yyyyyyyyyy - Aaaaaaaaaaa - Bbbbbbbb ccc Dddddddddddddd - abc1234560 - 2009-03-26 – 235959.pdf

Now I've read a couple of sections in RFC2183:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt

For instance

> A short (length <= 78 characters)    parameter value containing
>   only non-`tspecials' characters SHOULD be    represented as a single`
>   token'.  A short parameter value containing    only ASCII characters,
>   but including `tspecials' characters, SHOULD    be represented as`
>   quoted-string'.  Parameter values longer than 78    characters, or
>   which contain non-ASCII characters, MUST be encoded as    specified in
>   [RFC 2184].

Etc etc. Now there are millions of things that can go wrong, if I don't read through all of those RFC's... Or I choose a library which handles such RFC specifications. Is there any such thing for Java? Or am I paranoid, and actually it's sufficient to just write this header to the out stream:

```
String filename = "\"" + filename.replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";
addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 2183 isn't relevant, RFC 6266 is.

Also, the 78 character limit only applies to email, not http, so you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem in past and found the following solution.

The first URL looks like http://myhost.com/file/1234 
where 1234 is the file ID. Let's say that the file name should be `my-very-long-file-name.pdf`. So, instead of setting HTTP header  redirect the call to URL like

http://myhost.com/download/1234/my-very-long-file-name.pdf

The sevlet mapped to `/download/` will take ID from URL and print the file to its output stream. But browser will extract the file name from URL and offer you to download and save the file because its name is into the URL. I hope this will work for you also for long file names.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Unfortunately, for security reasons, we use URL encryption, so the URL is not available to the application... :-/

Comment: +1 I'm doing it this way too, because browser support for RFC2183/RFC2184 is poor at best and this is the only way to have non-ascii names working across all browsers.

Comment: non-ASCII names work the same way in all browsers except Safari (and ancient IEs)